# Preventing code duplication in and outside of a loop

Tags: c++, loops, code-duplication

I have a problem rewriting a loop:

```
else if( "d" == option || "debug" == option )
{
    debug(debug::always) << "commandline::set_internal_option::setting debug options: "
                         << value << ".\n";
    string::size_type index = 0;
    do
    {
        const string::size_type previous_index = index+1;
        index=value.find( ',', index );
        const string item = value.substr(previous_index, index);
        debug::type item_enum;
        if( !map_value(lib::debug_map, item, item_enum) )
            throw lib::commandline_error( "Unknown debug type: " + item, argument_number );

        debug(debug::always) << "commandline::set_internal_option::enabling " << item
                             << " debug output.\n";
        debug(debug::always) << "\n-->s_level=" << debug::s_level << "\n";
        debug::s_level = static_cast<debug::type>(debug::s_level ^ item_enum);
        debug(debug::always) << "\n-->s_level=" << debug::s_level << "\n";
    } while( index != string::npos );
}
```

`value` is something like `string("commandline,parser")` and the problem is that in the first run, I need `substr(previous_index, index)`, but in every subsequent iteration I need `substr(previous_index+1, index)` to skip over the comma. Is there some easy way I'm overlooking or will I have to repeat the call to `find` outside the loop for the initial iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not update `previous_index` after taking the `substr`?

```
string::size_type index = 0;
string::size_type previous_index = 0;
do {
  index=value.find( ',', previous_index );
  const string item = value.substr(previous_index, index);
  previous_index = index+1;
} while( index != string::npos );
```

Unchecked, but this should do the trick (with only one more word of memory).

Comment: You sir, are the winner. This is exactly the simple thing I was overlooking. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Since your goal is to prevent code duplication:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
boost::split(v, value, [](char c) { c == ','; });
```

If you want to create your own split function, you can do something like this:

```
template<typename PredicateT>
std::vector<std::string> Split(const std::string & in, PredicateT p)
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    auto b = in.begin();
    auto e = b;
    do {
        e = std::find_if(b, in.end(), p);
        v.emplace_back(b,e);
        b = e + 1;        
    } while (e != in.end());

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer no boost. +1 though. As to why no Boost: I haven't seen a good reason yet. C++11 has been good enough.

Comment: Then write a simple string splitting routine in C++11.

Comment: @rubenvb: Then take a look at boost's implementation, and write a split function for your own personal library.  This is one of the most useful functions that exists for text processing.  I guarantee you will need it again.

Comment: boost::split, boost::lexical_cast, boost::iterators, boost::mult-array, boost::multi-index, ...

Answer (score 1):

Start at `-1`?

```
string::size_type index = -1;
do
{
    const string::size_type previous_index = index + 1;
    index=value.find(',', previous_index);
    const string item = value.substr(previous_index, index - previous_index);
} while( index != string::npos );
```

Comment: `size_t(-1) + 1 != 0`. I checked.

Comment: Negate my last comment, I was mistesting (if there is such a thing). You're the runner-up IMO.

Answer (score 0):

A stupid (and somewhat unreadable) solution would be something like this:

```
string::size_type once = 0;
/* ... */
const string::size_type previous_index = index+1 + (once++ != 0); // or !!once
```

Comment: Hmmm... That be equivalent to an `if` inside the loop really `:(`

Answer (score 0):

First, I think there's a small error:

In your code, the expression `index=value.find( ',', index );` doesn't change the value of `index` if it already is the index of a comma character within the string (which is always the case except for the first loop iteration).

So you might want to replace `while( index != string::npos );` with `while( index++ != string::npos );` and `previous_index = index+1` with `previous_index = index`.

This should also solve your original problem.

To clarify:

```
string::size_type index = 0;
do
{
    const string::size_type previous_index = index;
    index = value.find( ',', index );
    const string item = value.substr(previous_index, index - previous_index);
} while( index++ != string::npos );
```